# capturing a child value in Firebase rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, rules

Using Firebase, it's possible to create rule expressions tp protect data but I've found it can quickly become complex.
One case I'm looking at has a rule using the children of the current node, e.g.:

```
data.child('value').val() === true
```

It's also possible to create a rule based on the contents of another node:

```
root.hasChild($node_variable)
```

What I'd like to do is to combine these two, e.g.:

```
root.child(data.child('value')).hasChild($node_variable)
```

but this hybrid approach throws an error when I publish the combined rule.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: try root.child(data.child('value').val()).hasChild($node_variable)

Comment: Class David!  Nesting works when I use the val() side of an entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4119421/david) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488608/capturing-a-child-value-in-firebase-rules/44667208#comment75972189_44488608), the solution was

```
root.child(data.child('value').val()).hasChild($node_variabl‌​e)
```